# Dynamically creating charts

Tags: c#, charts

I am trying to dynamically create a chart for each drive in the computer, inside a form.

Each chart should be a pie chart that contains the amount of free space (colored green) and used space(colored red) in GBs.

But when I run the following code the only thing I see is blank rectangles with the titles of "C:\", "D:\" and so on.

Here is the code :

```
    public static void DrawCharts()
    {
        Chart[] charts = new Chart[DriveInfo.GetDrives().Length];
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        for (int i = 0; i < drives.Length; i++)
        {
            charts[i] = new Chart();
            charts[i].Palette = ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel;
            charts[i].Titles.Add(drives[i].Name);
            charts[i].Series.Add("Storage");
            charts[i].Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
            charts[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20 + i * 231, 30);
            charts[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(230, 300);
            DataPoint d = new DataPoint();
            d.XValue = 1;
            double[] p = { (double)drives[i].TotalFreeSpace / 1000000000 };
            d.YValues = p;
            d.Color = System.Drawing.Color.YellowGreen;
            d.Label = "Free Space";
            charts[i].Series[0].Points.Add(d);
            d.Label = "Used Space";
            d.XValue = 2;
            double[] a = { (double)((drives[i].TotalSize - drives[i].TotalFreeSpace) / 1000000000) };
            d.YValues = a;
            d.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            charts[i].Series[0].Points.Add(d);
            Form1.tabs.TabPages[1].Controls.Add(charts[i]);
            charts[i].Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

But the most basic thing you need to add to a dynamically created chart..:

```
charts[i] = new Chart();
```

..is a `ChartArea`:

```
charts[i].ChartAreas.Add("CA1"); // pick your name!
```

Without it no `Series` can display..

Use it to style the axis with `TickMarks`, `GridLines` or `Labels` or to set `Minima` and `Maxima` and `Intervals`. Well, at least for most other `ChartTypes`; `Pies` don't need any of this anyway..

Note that you can have several `ChartAreas` in one `Chart`.

Also note that it still will display nothing until at least one `Series` has at least one `DataPoint`..

Comment: Yes, at least if you add something like this `d = new DataPoint();` after adding the 1st DataPoint..

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out after I ran the code once. Thanks.